# Github page shows master branch, not gh-pages

Tags: git, github

I've managed to push files to the master branch of my repo as well as a second branch called `gh-pages`. When I launch `mysite.github.io` it shows the contents of the master branch. Is there a way to redirect it to `gh-pages` instead?

I'm doing this from the Mac terminal.

Answer (score 27):

It sounds like you're confusing User / Organization pages with Project pages.

[User / Organization pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages) live in a specially named repository called `username.github.io`, and publish from the `master` branch. They can be browsed at `http://username.github.io`.

[Project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages) can be part of any repository, and are published from the special `gh-pages` branch. They can be browsed at `http://username.github.io/project-name`.

If you want to have a project page, make sure that your repository is not named after your GitHub user name. If you want your project to be available at `http://username.github.io`, you *must* have a User / Organization Page, which *must* publish from the `master` branch.

Comment: If i am deleting the master ,publish to gh-pages what will happen

Comment: If your Pages site is a User or Organization one (named `username.github.io`), I believe your site won't work anymore. Rename your repository to something else, which will move your site to `username.github.io/repo-name`, if you want to use `gh-pages`. Or leave the repo name, but rename your branches so that your web content is in `master`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this on the repository setting:

[image]

Comment: Not actual for user/organization's Pages source. Gives "User pages must be built from the master branch."
I don't like that I have to move everything to another branch now and deploy HTML to master. -_- GitHub, please fix this already.